# How to create `ee-jwt-secret-file` for Teku node with Alchemy

Tags: alchemy, teku

I am looking to run a Teku node, but instead of connecting it to my own execution client, I'm looking to connect to a node as a service.

1. Is this possible
2. How do I create a `ee-jwt-secret-file` from Alchemy or other node-as-a-service?

The command to run a Teku node is as follows:

```
teku \
    --ee-endpoint=<ALCHEMY_API_ENDPOINT> \
    --ee-jwt-secret-file=jwtsecret.hex  \
    --metrics-enabled=true              \
    --rest-api-enabled=true
```

I am unsure how to create the `jwtsecret.hex` file.

I am not planning on having this be a validator with $, just want to make read calls to the beacon node.

The current [alchemy docs](https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/setting-up-an-eth-20-staking-validator-with-teku) are outdated at the moment.